# Replace variable value in configmap with value from values.yaml (helm)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've created configMap with values

my values look like that:

values.yaml

```
ports:
  app:
  - port: 8080
    name: http
  - port: 9090
    name: admin
```

now I would like to use it in configmap as:

configmap.yaml

```
variable: {{ (first .Values.ports.app.port) }}
```

but when I'm doing it I have an error:

```
can't evaluate field Port in type interface {}
```

Comment: Did you mean `(first .Values.ports.app).port`?

Comment: @Botje, exactly! Thanks!

btw. is it possible to pick a port where name = admin?

Comment: Ok I did it. `{{- range .Values.ports.app }}
          {{- if eq .name "admin" }} {{ .port }} {{- end }}
        {{- end }}`